# Open Edge v11 Drill down button bug

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have a problem and I am not sure if it is a Progress(Open Edge) bug or if there is something wrong with my code.

I have a main container forum from which I call child functions to display with in the MDI Parent. Each child can also call subsequent function which will be parented to the caller child function, overlapping the frame.

*Now the problem is* when I open the same child function twice and drill down on both and return to the calling child form on the first function, the button I used to drill down to the sub-function will no longer trigger on the first child function but will still work on the second child function.

I will not be able to supply the code example for this so I hope what I explained is understandable.

Could someone please tell me what is causing this and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you define the trigger for your button in child function on the child object. make sure, that your trigger is only once defined.

Comment: Ok my apologies, it would seem that the child windows does not have to be the same window it could be two different windows and the effect will still be the same. Now if you say trigger do you mean the object's trigger self or the trigger 'CHOOSE' on the button object because the trigger it self would be defined for each button separately.

Comment: I mean the Statement "ON". Typicaly is it a definition like this "ON CHOOSE OF pbButton IN FRAME frmFrame DO:".
Error, that a trigger reacts on other object as has been thought comes often in scripts, where is the trigger definition dynamically programmed and the trigger is registred first by running the precudure.

Comment: please see this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122009/value-changing-event-in-browser/10148626#10148626